# Simple Q Javascript - Why does this return false?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why does this return false?  I would think the for loop should encounter the first 3, satisfy the if conditional and then return true.  Thanks for any help.

```js
  var array = [3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3];

  function some(array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (array[i] == true) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  };

  console.log(some(array));
  // false
```

Comment: because none of your array items == true ... when comparing a number to true, it's only == if the number is 1 - I think true is "coerced" to a 1 for the comparison

Comment: Well, nothing is equal to true.

3 == true; // false
0 == true; // false

etc.

Comment: to see this in action, if you `console.log(5 + true);` you get 6

Comment: @JaromandaX: Yep, that's exactly right. In fact, whenever you compare against a boolean, the boolean is converted to a number. So `[1,2,3] == true` is actually doing `[1,2,3] == 1`.

Comment: Yet another reason to check `if ((b == true) != false)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It returns false because you are comparing to `true` and none of the values in your array are `true` or 1 (which javascript considers to be `true`). If you modify your check to just check the truthiness of the values then you would get the value you expect.

```js
var array = [3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3];

  function some(array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (array[i]) { //Notice we just check for a truthy value
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  };

  console.log(some(array));
```

Comment: note, if a value was `1` then that would evaluate to true in the original code

Comment: *"none of the values in your array are `true` or 1"* any value that converts to `1` would work, e.g. `'1'`, `[1]`, `{toString() { return '1';}}`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I always forget about javascript's use of toString.

Answer (score 0):

The condition (array[i] == true) will check whether the value of array[i] is "true" (Boolean) or not.

From your array variable, no array [i] has value "true" (Boolean), then the condition (array[i] == true) is always false.